# Manually insert users from seed file with accounts-password

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to seed users into accounts-password? Something like:

```
  Users.insert
    email: 'test@test.com'
    password: 'secret'
```

I've tried many things but no luck yet. Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easiest to do this on the server when it starts:

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      password: 'password'
    });
  }
});
```